# What should I use as a starting point each month for counting how much of my resources the user consumes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, payment, stripe-payments

Say, I use stripe subscriptions for my users with one plan which is $10 per month for 100 API requests and that's the standard price. However, if the user has used 150 API requests, I charge them $3 more on top on $10. For 200 and more requests it's total of $17.

Say, I've subscribed the user on October 9th. On November 9th they will be charged again by Stripe. When should I "freeze" the amount of the APIs the user has used during the month to calculate the overall price and start counting from zero again for the new period of November 9th - December 9th?

As far as I'm concerned, it's either on `payment.success` or `invoice.success` event in my  stripe web hook controller. However, I think it's not reliable because:

1. Which one is it exactly - `payment.success` or `invoice.success` - the one I need? They occur both, as far as I know sometimes `payment.success` occurs **first**, sometimes - `invoice.success` and it's unknown which one occurs first in each particular case.
2. Theres's the time period between these 2 events, I don't know how long exactly, probably a few minutes. But during those few minutes the user might consume at least one Invoice
3. I'm not sure if it's guaranteed that for each user the events  `payment.success` and `invoice.success` occur **only once** per month. Do they really? If not it's even less reliable to use them to achieve my goal.
4. `invoice.created` event occurs 1 hour before the Invoice is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Um. Why wouldn't it be the moment your user clicked 'BUY'? The fact it took an hour/day for payment to be received isn't relevant is it?  Think about iOS apps.  I can buy the app right now, but most of the time I don't get an invoice from Apple for several days (even a week sometimes).

I think you're going to be frustrated trying to time it to events from your payment provider.  IMHO that should be done within your app.

Comment: **I use stripe subscriptions...** - recurring payments.