# The date-time of invoice.created even in Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

Is there any way to determine the exact date and time when an the event `invoice.created` occurred, given that Invoice?

For example:

```
inv = Stripe::Invoice.retrieve(....)
# when did `invoice.created ` occurred for "inv"?
```

As far I know, `period_end` reflects the date-time of `invoice.payment_succeeded`. I guess I can take `period_end` and subtract 1 hour (as the documentation says), but 1 hour isn't exact time, somewhere I read it was a few hours, what's more is that there might be the failing attempts to charge the user, thus there's might an additional **delay** between them so just subtracting 1 hour doesn't give me the exact time of `invoice.created`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution here would be to listen to the `invoice.created` event with a webhook and store the `created` value (or at least the event id) in your database.

You are correct that the invoice would be closed after an hour but only once all the webhooks have successfully returned a `200` response code to the request. Otherwise the webhook would be resent every hour up to 3 days until success before the invoice could be closed [[1](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_events)].

You could otherwise use the [List Events API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_events) and filter events by date with the `created` parameter and `type` where you would put `invoice.created` and would allow you to find the event after the fact and retrieve the `created` value.

You could also look into the `webhooks_delivered_at` field on the Invoice object but that would not work if you webhooks failed for some reason on first delivery.

Comment: `Stripe::Event.all` is not reliable because it's the list of the 30 days only, is it? The best solution is to store all the events sent into my database, huh?

Comment: I mean I assumed you wanted to get the date when getting `invoice.payment_succeeded` which would happen before 30 days. If you want to display the exact info of creation date I don't think there's a better way. Otherwise use the `date` field if you just want to display a date for your invoice

Comment: The reason I need to store the date of "invoice.created" and then retrieve it is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836824/what-should-i-use-as-a-starting-point-each-month-for-counting-how-much-of-my-res

Comment: Once you get `invoice.created` you create the Invoice Item for for example 1200 API calls. At that point on your end you "reset" your counter for the next invoice and you don't care whether the invoice is paid later or not. You then store *this* date on your database.  If you don't pay you mobile phone invoice for 5 days, the call you make after the invoice are still billed on the next invoice, your company wouldn't update the invoice all the time

Comment: I don't have something to reset, by resetting I meant finding the moment from which I can start counting the API calls  from zero. So storing the date of "invoice.created" in a database seems to be the only correct way.

Comment: I don't think it is. For me the time you should use is the time at which you create the invoice item for these API calls. From that point you should start counting API calls to the next invoice. But that means saving this value on your database instead or relying on the item in Stripe which makes more sense (for me)

Comment: `is the time at which you create the invoice item` == `invoice.created` event - that's what I said.

Comment: is it correct that having the id of an event, I can retrieve it anytime, even when 30 days have passed?

Comment: No you can't you need to store the events or the date on your end.

Comment: Do you have a link prooving that an event older than 30 days can't be retrieved by its id?

Comment: it doesn't say that, does it?

Comment: I mean if you just read it yes it does: `NOTE: Right now, we only guarantee access to events for 30 days. `

Comment: it depends what access they mean, are you sure it's Event.retrieve(...) and not Event.all? I figure they mean Event.all.

Comment: Ok then you're gonna have to try retrieving 30+ days events on your account and just see for yourself I guess